# How to change a record for all IDs, JOIN and concatenate

Tags: mysql, sql

To clarify, my question that I formulated is, "Change the emails for all members of Sonata lastname@sonata.org, where lastname is the member's actual last name".

There are three tables in question. The first two are Members and the second is Artists, they are related using the xRefArtistsMembers. They are as follows:

```
Members
-------
MemberID, Firstname, Lastname, Address, Email

Artists
-------
ArtistID, ArtistName, City, Region, WebAddress

XrefArtistsMembers
------------------
ArtistID, MemberID
```

I formulated the following query:

```
alter a.*
from artists a
left join xrefartistsmembers x on x.artistid = a.artistid
left join members m on m.memberid = x.memberid
and m.email = m.lastname + ' % @sonata.org';
```

Unfortunately, it does not compile. Again, my question that I conjured to yeild my concept is, How to change the emails for all members of Sonata lastname@sonata.org, where lastname is the member's actual last name.

Comment: alter is used for changing table structure , here you need to use update

Comment: OK if its Update I'll need to use SET

Comment: What do you need to change the email to?

Comment: I just need to indicate that I CAN change it until further notice, I guess null for now

Comment: Why are you trying to perform addition on strings?

Comment: That, I think is the concatenation

Comment: In MySQL, `+` is addition. Concatenation is the `CONCAT()` function. Also, why are you concatenating `space % space` into the address?

Comment: Perhaps, I am out of the 'ballpark' with this attempt at finding all members of Sonata where the lastname is the members actual last name

Comment: Why do you need to join? `email` and `lastname` are both in the same table, what do you need from the other tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE members m
JOIN xrefartistsmembers x ON x.memberid = x.memberid
JOIN artists a ON x.artistid = a.artistid
SET m.email = whatever
WHERE m.email = CONCAT(m.lastname, '@sonata.org')
```

I'm not sure what the point of the JOIN is. Maybe this simpler query is enough:

```
UPDATE members m
SET m.email = whatever
WHERE m.email = CONCAT(m.lastname, '@sonata.org')
```

Comment: We need the join because the Members of Sonata is an ArtistName. It might help to have the records..

Comment: Do you mean that `whatever` will use something from `artists`? OK.

Answer (score 0):

For any database

```
UPDATE Members SET Email='new email'
WHERE Email = Lastname + '@sonata.org'
      AND MemberID IN (SELECT MemberID FROM XrefArtistsMembers)
```